# How do you launch Elite Dangerous in monitor/Oculus Rift mode with separate shortcuts?

Tags: elite-dangerous, oculus-rift

Are there any command line arguments to facilitate launching Elite Dangerous in the regular monitor and rift modes without having to go to in-game settings?

If not, are the graphics settings stored somewhere in a file that could be modified with a script before launch, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out i found the answer myself. Files are stored here:

`C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Frontier Developments\Elite Dangerous\Options\Graphics`

First set it up for Oculus, copy all the files and save them somewhere, then set it up for your monitor and copy the files out.

Then when you want to play either using the Oculus or your monitor, just copy and replace the files in the folder or write a simple script for it.